# How to set default value for a function that returns something?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to use context with React TypeScript. This is my code:

```
interface ContextType {
   isModalOpen: boolean;
   openModal: () => void;
   closeModal: () => void;
   getToday: () => {
     date: number;
     month: number;
     year: number;
   };
}

const defaultContextValues:ContextType = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  openModal: () => {},
  closeModal: () => {},
  getToday: () => {},  // getting error here
};

const AppContext = createContext<ContextType>(defaultContextValues);

export const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(defaultContextValues.isModalOpen);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  const getToday = (): {
    date: number;
    month: number;
    year: number;
  } => {
    const date = new Date();
    let yr = date.getFullYear();
    let mo = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let dt = date.getDate();

    return { date: dt, month: mo, year: yr };
  };

return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        isModalOpen,
        openModal,
        closeModal,
        getToday,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export default useGlobalContext;
```

and the error message is:

```
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '() => { date: number; month: number; year: number; }'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{ date: number; month: number; year: number; }'.
```

How can I set a default value for the function 'getToday'? Since it is returning some value, using '() => {}' is not correct.

Comment: What is unclear from the error? `() => {}` is a function that doesn't return anything, certainly not an object with numerical `date`, `month` and `year` properties. You evidently know how to write a function that does, since your implementation includes one.

Comment: You could even pull `getToday` out of the component and use it as the default value.